# Cannot set a global variable inside a onload method

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building an Angular 9 app.
In this app I got an image upload component.

In order to make sure the right things are uploaded I want to check the dimensions of selected images. I do this with the code below (which kind of works).

```
let img = new Image();
          img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileList[index]);
          img.onload = () => {
            if (img.width < this.allowedWidth && img.height < this.allowedHeight) {
              this.uploadValid = true;
              this.isDoneUploading = false;
            } else {
              this.uploadValid = false;
              this.uploadErrorMessage = this.getTranslation('files.forms.labels.error_dimenstions');
            }
          }
```

I can access the this.allowedWidth and this.allowedHeight variables that I set at the top of the component page but strangly I cannot set the this.uploadValid and this.uploadErrorMessage variables.

Or at least I cannot set them at a "global" context of the component only within the If/else statement.

I tried the following code too but it does not help.

```
let img = new Image();
let that = this;
              img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileList[index]);
              img.onload = () => {
                if (img.width < that.allowedWidth && img.height < that.allowedHeight) {
                  that.uploadValid = true;
                  that.isDoneUploading = false;
                } else {
                  that.uploadValid = false;
                  that.uploadErrorMessage = that.getTranslation('files.forms.labels.error_dimenstions');
                }
              }
```

**Update**

This is the whole method in which this method resides.
It is called when a file is selected.

```
handleDrop(fileList: FileList) {
    this.files = [];
    this.isDropzoneActive = false;
    this.uploadingFileCount += fileList.length
    for (let index = 0; index < fileList.length; index++) {
      if (this.allowedTypes.includes(fileList[index].type)) {
        if (fileList[index].size < this.allowedSize) {
          let img = new Image();
          img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileList[index]);
          img.onload = () => {
            if (img.width < this.allowedWidth && img.height < this.allowedHeight) {
              this.uploadValid = true;
              this.isDoneUploading = false;
            } else {
              this.uploadValid = false;
              this.uploadErrorMessage = this.getTranslation('files.forms.labels.error_dimenstions');
            }
          }
        } else {
          this.uploadValid = false;
          this.uploadErrorMessage = this.getTranslation('files.forms.labels.error_size');
        }
      } else {
        this.uploadValid = false;
        this.uploadErrorMessage = this.getTranslation('files.forms.labels.error_format');
      }
      const item = {
        id: null,
        file_name: fileList[index].name,
        file_type: fileList[index].type,
        file_size: fileList[index].size,
        file_url: null
      }
      this.uploadItems.push(item);
      const file = {
        id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 15),
        file: fileList[index],
        uploaded: false,
        valid: this.uploadValid,
        error: this.uploadErrorMessage
      }
      console.log(file);
      this.uploadQueue.push(file);
    }
    // this.submitUploadForm();
  }
```

Comment: Please show how this is code enclosed and how is it invoked?

Comment: Please include more code. Here it's hard to get the context of the code you've shared, component structure etc. Usually image imports are made in directives not component and included in the form. You should also use FormControl instead of your own variables.

Comment: I have updated the question with the whole method. Thank you! @Jean-XavierRaynaud

Comment: This is a long shot but try to make the event handler an arrow function: `handleDrop = (fileList: FileList) => {...}`

Comment: It unfortunately did not work either. It is very strange that I can access the values of this.allowedWidth but I cannot set the values (at least not so that it is changed globally).

Answer (score 0):

Using a directive and a FormControl for a similar problem, my code looks like this:

directive:

```
// angular imports
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// models imports
import { FileHandle } from '../models';


@Directive({
 selector: '[appFilesDrop]'
})
export class FilesDropDirective {
  @Output() files: EventEmitter<FileHandle[]> = new EventEmitter();

  @HostBinding('style.background') private background = '#eee';

  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { }

  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) public onDragOver(evt: DragEvent) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.background = '#999';
  }

  @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event']) public onDragLeave(evt: DragEvent) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.background = '#eee';
  }

  @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public onDrop(evt: DragEvent) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.background = '#eee';

    const files: FileHandle[] = [];
    // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
    for (let i = 0; i < evt.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
      const file = evt.dataTransfer.files[i];
      const url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
      files.push({ file, url });
    }
    if (files.length > 0) {
      this.files.emit(files);
    }
  }
}
```

models.ts:

```
export interface FileHandle {
  url: SafeUrl;
  file?: File;
}
```

html code:

```
<!-- Image upload field -->
        <ng-container *ngIf="formField.type === 'filesUpload'" class="example-full-width image-field-container">
          <mat-form-field
            appearance="outline"
            floatLabel="always"
            class=".example-full-width"
          >
              <mat-label>{{ objectName }} {{formField.label}}</mat-label>
              <!-- This block is only displayed if there's no image -->
              <!-- it's necessary because we need a formControlName in a mat-form-field -->
              <input
                *ngIf="formGroup.controls[formField.key].value === null"
                class="image-input"
                matInput
                [formControlName]="formField.key"
                type="text"
                appFilesDrop
                [placeholder]="formField.placeholder"
                autocomplete="off"
                (files)="filesDropped($event, formField.key)"
                readonly
              >
              <!-- Display errors if any -->
              <mat-error
                *ngIf="formGroup.controls[formField.key].hasError('required') && (formGroup.controls[formField.key].dirty || formGroup.controls[formField.key].touched)"
              >
                A {{formField.label.toLocaleLowerCase()}} is required
              </mat-error>
              <mat-error     *ngIf="formGroup.controls[formField.key].hasError('tooLongArray')">
                You must drop only one image, you dropped {{formGroup.controls[formField.key].errors.tooLongArray.length}} images.
              </mat-error>
              <mat-error     *ngIf="formGroup.controls[formField.key].hasError('forbiddenMime')">
                You must drop files of type {{formGroup.controls[formField.key].errors.forbiddenMime.forbidden.join(', ')}}.
                All your files must be of type {{formGroup.controls[formField.key].errors.forbiddenMime.allowed.join(', ')}}
              </mat-error>
              <mat-error     *ngIf="formGroup.controls[formField.key].hasError('tooLargeFile')">
                The file(s) {{formGroup.controls[formField.key].errors.tooLargeFile.forbidden.join(', ')}} is/are too big.
                The maximum allowed size is     {{formGroup.controls[formField.key].errors.tooLargeFile.allowed/1024 | number}}kb
              </mat-error>
              <!-- If we have an image we need to display it. -->
              <!-- We created a hidden mat-form-field and display the image -->
              <ng-container *ngIf="formGroup.controls[formField.key].value !== null">
                <div class="">
                  <input matInput [formControlName]="formField.key" style="visibility: hidden;" class="invisible">
                  <img [src]="formGroup.controls[formField.key].value[0].url" class="image-uploaded">
                </div>
                <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="removeFiles(formField.key)"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></button>
              </ng-container>
          </mat-form-field>
        </ng-container>
```

The overall validation logic is a bit complex because I'm using a service which is generating the FormGroup dynamically but the logic is easy to understand even if you can't copy/paste it:

```
// file fields
        case('filesUpload'): {
          const options = field.options as FileFieldOptions;

          // build the validators
          validators.push(mimeTypeValidator(options.allowedMimes));
          if (!options.multiple) { validators.push(arrayLengthValidator(1)); }
          if (options.maxSize) { validators.push(fileSizeValidator(options.maxSize)); }

          // get the initial value
          if (!options.multiple && initialValue && initialValue[field.key]) {
            // we only have 1 object, so we will have on url from the api and we can provide the formControl as a 1 object control
            initialFieldValue = [{
              url: initialValue[field.key]
            }] as Array<FileHandle>;
          }
          break;
```

Forgot to add the example of validators:

```
For the file size validator:
    // angular imports
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl, } from '@angular/forms';

// model imports
import { FileHandle } from '../models';

export function fileSizeValidator(maxFileSize: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    // validate when there's no value
    if (control.value === null || control.value === undefined ) { return     null; }
    // validate when we only have a url (it comes from server)
    if (control.value[0].file === undefined) { return null; }
    const fileHandles = control.value as Array<FileHandle>;
    const tooLargeFiles = fileHandles.filter(fileHandle => fileHandle.file.size > maxFileSize).map(fileHandle => fileHandle.file.name);
    return tooLargeFiles.length > 0 ? {tooLargeFile: {forbidden: tooLargeFiles, allowed: maxFileSize}} : null;
  };
}
```

and a MimeType validator:

```
// angular imports
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl, } from '@angular/forms';

// model imports
import { FileHandle } from '../models';

export function mimeTypeValidator(allowedMimeTypes: Array<string>): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    // validate when there's no value
    if (control.value === null || control.value === undefined ) { return null; }
    // validate when we only have a url (it comes from server)
    if (control.value[0].file === undefined) { return null; }
    const fileHandles = control.value as Array<FileHandle>;
    const forbiddenMimes = fileHandles.map(fileHandle => fileHandle.file.type).filter(mime => !allowedMimeTypes.includes(mime));
    return forbiddenMimes.length > 0 ? {forbiddenMime: {forbidden: forbiddenMimes, allowed: allowedMimeTypes}} : null;
  };
}
```